# How to cross-reference an equation without using \label and \ref?

Tags: cross-referencing

I use

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
```

It means when I make an equation. I just need to do this

```
\begin{equation}
    equation
\end{equation}
```

And it's numbered automatically.

So how can I cross-reference the equation numbered (1.2)? I don't `\label` it, so `\ref` is not helpful.

Comment: `\ref{<equation label>}`? for more, please provide minimal working example with only relevant packages.

Comment: tyou proved only code sniped, not minimal working example :(

Comment: Any particular reason for not wanting to use LaTeX's label-ref cross-referencing mechanism?

Comment: @Mico is this more convenient. Labeling everything is more complicated

Comment: How inconvenient can it be to have to write `\label{eq:second}` and `\ref{eq:second}`? Is your paper really short? If so, just write "... as shown in equation (1.2) ..." and be done with it. I've edited the title of your posting to clarify your typesetting objective, which isn't really related to the directive `\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}`.

Comment: @chítrungchâu: Yes, it's cumbersome, but it's easier in the long run. Analogously, there's ample food around and you have to eat. It's cumbersome to go out and get the feed, but you need to do that. It's better for you in the long run.

Comment: (La)TeX is software that typesets your content, it is not aware of the content. Te software cannot know, what you ant to reference. It is just a piece of software.

Comment: there appears to be a misunderstanding here. The main reason for needing `\label` and `\ref` in latex is _because_ `equation` and similar environments number automatically.  If you numbered the equation "by hand" as say equation 2 then you could refer to it as equation 2 with no command needed, but the automatic numbering is much more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{first}
\begin{equation}\label{eq: my very first referenced equation}
    equation
\end{equation}
see \eqref{eq: my very first referenced equation} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to run LaTeX at least twice.

*Addendum:*
From comments to your question and changes of question follows, that you actually not interested referencing mechanism ... An alternative is using `tag`s for numbering/tagging of equation and than referencing it manually:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}% or amsmath ...

\begin{document}
\chapter{first}
\begin{equation}\tag{1.1}
    equation
\end{equation}
see (1.1) \dots
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

If using `\label` and `\ref` (or `\eqref`) is too inconvenient for you, the leading alternative is to hard-code the cross-reference. E.g., if the equation of interest is numbered "(2.1)", you could write elsewhere

```
... as was shown in equation (2.1), ...
```

That said, you'll save yourself a lot of time and effort in the medium to long run if you learn how to use `\label` and `\ref`.